# get tar trailing garbage with python

Tags: python, tar

While I extract tar file with `tar -xvf test` I see

`gzip:stdin: decompression ON,trailing garbage ignored`

How can I split the tar file to 2 files :

1. tar file , that not return `trailing garbage ignored` while extracting
2. trailing garbage

Can I recognize the suffix of tar file so I can cut the data there?